# Find the area of $(x^2+y^2)^2 \le 4x^2y$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

I have to find the area of a set of points given with:
$$(x^2+y^2)^2 \le 4x^2y ;\quad (x,y) \in {\rm I\!R}^2$$
and I don't really know how to start.

Comment: In polar coordinates this region is just$$r\le 4\cos^2{(\theta)}\sin{(\theta)}\quad 0\le\theta\le\pi$$

Comment: Could you maybe explain how do you get to that?

Comment: Using $x=r\cos\theta$ etc., then cancelling $r^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @PeterForeman noted, the region is $(r^2)^2\le4(r\cos\theta)^2r\sin\theta$ or equivalently $r\le4\cos^2\theta\sin\theta$, so $\theta\in[0,\,\pi]$. Its area is$$\begin{align}\int_0^\pi\tfrac12(4\cos^2\theta\sin\theta)^2d\theta&=8\int_0^\pi\cos^4\theta\sin^2\theta d\theta\\&=16\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^4\theta\sin^2\theta d\theta\\&=8\operatorname{B}\left(\tfrac52,\,\tfrac32\right)\\&=\tfrac{\pi}{2}.\end{align}$$